# Why do I get array of nulls in my database?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of ids which is `launchIds`. 
I'm trying to push it on a model field `trips` with 
`$addToSet: { trips: { $each: launchIds }`. This gives me an error: `Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value \"[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]\...`

if I try to map through `launchIds` and convert to `Mongoose.Shema.Types.ObjectId` I get in the database `trips: [null,null,null]`

`lauchIds = ['1','2','3']`

```
  async bookTrips({ launchIds }) {
    let userId = "5bf7f7b3817119363da48403";

    const mongoIds = launchIds.map(l => Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(l));

    return this.store.User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      {
        $addToSet: { trips: { $each: mongoIds } }
      },
      { new: true }
    );
  }
```

Here's my model Schema:

```
  const UserSchema = new Mongoose.Schema(
    {
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      token: String,
      trips: [
        {
          type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "trip"
        }
      ]
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
```

I'm passing ids via grapql playground. Here's my `mutation`:

```
bookTrips: async (_, { launchIds }, { dataSources }) => {
  console.log(launchIds);
  // logs ['1','2','3']
  console.log(typeof launchIds);
  //Object 

  const results = await dataSources.userAPI.bookTrips({ launchIds });
  console.log(results);

  return { message: "hello" };
}
```

Comment: It looks like launchIds is an escaped string of some kind.  Can you show us where you are actually setting that variable? (I.e how are you calling ```booktrips```?

Comment: Updated the post. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Can we see the console out, as well as ```console.log(typeof launchIds)```;?

Comment: Hmm... it's an Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting back an array of strings where this should be numbers

The solution:

**My model** (same as above):

```
  const UserSchema = new Mongoose.Schema(
    {
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      token: String,
      trips: [
        {
          type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "trip"
        }
      ]
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
```

**crud API:**

```
  async bookTrips({ launchIds }) {
    let userId = "5bf7f7b3817119363da48403";

    const idsToNums = launchIds.map(Number);
    const mongoIds = idsToNums.map(l => Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(l));

    return this.store.User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      {
        $push: { trips: { $each: mongoIds } }
      },
      { new: true }
    );
  }
```

Notice the `Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` on model and `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` on api. If I remove `Schema` from model or add `Schema` to api I'm getting an error. Not sure why, but the above example works. I hope someone will find this helpful or suggests a better solution.

Comment: Someone ( actually the original author ) already explained why https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1671:

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string or a number into mongo object use `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId`,

```
const mongoIds = launchIds.map(l => Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(l));
```

Comment: I get an error : `"Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"`

Comment: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(1) => 000000012a5f832b959ac1a4. I'm getting no error.

Comment: change Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId => Mongoose.Types.ObjectId

Comment: Throws me an error in the console: `node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:681
        throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at array `' + path +
        ^

TypeError: Undefined type `ObjectID` at array `trips``

Comment: can u check this https://repl.it/@rajasekarm/Stackoverflow-mongoose-issue-fix, click run to see the output

Comment: I think I found an issue. `const ids = ['1', '2', '3']; const idsToNums=ids.map(Number);`  I'm getting an array of strings and not numbers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184169/discussion-between-raja-sekar-and-karolis2017).